# can an isp block incoming connections?

Tags: java, sockets, networking, network-programming

First of all, i am a newbie in network programming. Few days ago, i wanted to test a simple java server(simple java echo server). I first tried running it in a university computer and then tried connecting through my laptop which is in a different network without any success. I assumed the network(private university network) didn't allow the connection. Next, i ran the server in my laptop expecting it to be public. I ran the server. I ran it in port 5000. Since the connection was through wifi i also did port forwarding so that my router would know where to forward the incoming requests. I even disabled the firewall just to test. Then there is a tool in the internet which i obtained from some other user in stackoverflow http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ which can check if a port is open in a machine. I put my ipaddress and port number to see if it is reachable. It continued saying the port is closed. Although i don't have a good idea about networks, i called the ISP and asked if the issue was with the network being a private network and if it is possible to host server in my laptop, she concurred saying it was private network and what i am trying to do is not possible. I wanted to try it in some other computer. I met one good guy in stackoverflow who allowed me to run the server in his computer in taiwan. He disabled his firewall or added an exception, then ran the server. I then ran my client and it could successfully connect to his server. I was ecstatic.

So, my question and curiosity is how does isp blocking incoming connection work? Did the ISP really block the incoming connection to my server or could the problem be with some other things? Is it ever possible to host server in my laptop which is accessible to the world. I am still not content with the answer i got from the ISP which was it was private network so it was blocking..isn't internet basically the collection of private networks connected to each other so isn't everyone in one way or other part of a private network? Please help me with these dilemmas. Appreciate your effort and help a lot! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your house probably has one global external IP assigned to you by your ISP. They will normally block commonly used ports incoming, such as 80 (HTTP), 22 (SSH), 23 (Telnet), 25 (SMTP), and 443 (HTTPS). The majority of the remaining ports should be open for you to use.

As you have one global IP, and multiple devices on your network, you need to tell your router which computer the incoming traffic on a given port needs to go to. This is called Port Forwarding. As you don't control the routers upstream from you at your university, you can't change anything while there. At home you can.

Port Forwarding is explained in depth [here](http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/).

Comment: thanks for the reply but like i have already mentioned above i am pretty sure i configured port forwarding correctly in my router and also the server was run on port 5000.

Comment: @kofhearts Pretty late to the game, but running your server on your laptop at which port (5000 or otherwise) doesn't matter. What matters is what port is the external client trying to access, i.e, the port that is open on your router. Check if that port is not amongst the common ones here.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it depends on the ISP. I have been able to open ports before with mine, using port forwarding from my router.

As a technician who works for an ISP, I can also say that the tech support generally doesn't have a clue whenbit comes to port blocking or networking in general, they mostly follow a script and ask you if you have turned it off and on again. Maybe check that you are forwarding the port correctly?